# Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value '10,12' to data type int

Tags: php, sql, sql-server-2012, zend-framework2

```
$sSql = "SELECT * FROM table1 where field1 > 0 and field2 IN (:buzzGroups) and active = 1";
$arrParams = array('buzzGroups' => $vBuzzGroups);
$stmt = $this->tableGateway->getAdapter()->createStatement($sSql);
$stmt->prepare($sSql);
$data = $stmt->execute($arrParams);
```

Here is the value of `$vBuzzGroups = '10,12';`

when I pass only single value then it works but when I try with multiple values..that of comma separated it gives me the error,

```
Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value '10,12' to data type int
```

Is there any one who faced this issue?

Comment: You need to identify each IN value as a separate value, not as a comma-separated string.... otherwise it will be treated as a string

Comment: What's the type of the `field2`?

Comment: @vhu - the type is INT, but still it should work as similar to normal SQL query with IN query in which the values as passed with comma separated.

Comment: @GordonLinoff -  it is SQL Server..

Comment: In Doctrine I pass Parameter to IN as an Array `$vBuzzGroups = array(10,12)`. Maybe its the same here?

Comment: If you look carefully it is a duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/920353/can-i-bind-an-array-to-an-in-condition

Comment: @PaulF - I've seen this..but there is an issue with that process, they have taken the array directly to the execute statement(I mean replacing the '?' of IN query with a single array of variables that need to be send)..if that is the case, what happens if I have two IN statements in the same query.

Comment: @kumar: maybe you could adapt the solution by alan_mm (about 1/2 way down with two upvotes) & use a different prefix for each of the IN statements.

Answer (score 0):

Use implode() function to split values.

Try this updated code

```
$arrParams = array('buzzGroups' => $vBuzzGroups);
$sSql = "SELECT * FROM table1 where field1 > 0 and field2 IN 
(".implode(',',$arrParams).") and active = 1";
```